# Linux VPS host with graphical interface using RDP (not VNC)

Tags: vnc, vps

Our CEO's latest brain-waive is "More people will use our software product if it were all accessible from the web". He wants to dump a lot of (but not enough) resources in to taking a complex Linux-based GUI product we already have and re-writing it as a web application. I hope to head off this this disaster by demoing how we could just expose our existing software to the web using something like [Guacamole](http://www.guac-dev.org) + [X11rdp](http://scarygliders.net/tag/x11rdp/).

Problem is I really don't have time to set such a demo up. So I was wondering anyone could recommend me an existing VPS service which offers a purely JavaScript + HTML5 GUI interface (no Java Applets/Flash etc.). **Most importantly this must not use VNC as the video transport protocol as its performance sucks**. Anything that has an existing RDP based set-up would be great. Even an X11 protocol implemented in pure JavaScript would be better for our application.

As I say this is just for a demo so it doesn't have to be beautiful/scalable. I assume any such existing feature will be aimed at system administrators and might have a bunch of other irrelevant admin tools; this doesn't matter. I just need to show that without installing any software on say an OS X or Windows machine it is technically possible to provide a usable experience with our Linux-based GUI product from a web-browser.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/) instead of VNC?

I don't think there's any X11 implementation for RDP (server-sided).

Comment: Something using the NX protocol would be great. NoMachine used to have a web interface using a Java applet which is a PITA to set-up. They now have a product which is easy to get running but re-encodes all the video using H.264/VP8 etc. and so looks awful. The key is I don't have any time to set this up so I'd like something hosted.

Answer (score 0):

> I just need to show that without installing any software on say an OS X or Windows machine > it is technically possible to provide a usable experience with our Linux-based GUI product > from a web-browser.

NoMachine (NX) has Portal Server which lets you access your remote Linux desktop via the browser (www.nomachine.com).

The fact that

> They now have a product which is easy to get running but re-encodes all the video using 
>   H.264/VP8 etc. and so looks awful.

Nothing has changed for us in how the virtual desktop is visualized. With their help we fixed some settings and configuration, but what's important for us is that the users get the same desktop experience.

Comment: Do you have any further details on how this helped you, what you changed etc. to actually solve the problem. Without that this reads like an advertisement for a commercial service that you are recommending.

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search led to [this](http://www.cybelesoft.com/thinrdp/) page. Seems to be what you are looking for, don't know if you discarded that or we simply didn't do the same google search.